When I use Health package 10.2.0 of flutter, I can not access health connect by only AppStore released app in Android version below 13
Describe the bug
I am using Health package for only getting step count in my flutter app.
When I called requestAuthorization method of health package somewhere with useHealthConnectIfAvailable,
I got this error by only PlayStore released app in Android version below 13.
(My app can run it by PlayStore released app in Android14 and local release builded app in Android below 13 )
This app can't access Health Connect like the link
The Link wrote
Apps currently need to be allowlisted to get access to Health Connect. You can follow the process outlined at: https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect/frequently-asked-questions#q_how_do_i_request_access_to_readwrite_data_types
But I have approved the allowlist.
To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior -
Write code according to the10.2.0 of health package and release PlayStore.
Then call requestAuthorization method of health package somewhere.

AndroidManifest.xml (Only about health connect)

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hogehoge">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.healthdata" />
        <intent>
            <action android:name="androidx.health.ACTION_SHOW_PERMISSIONS_RATIONALE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.health.READ_STEPS"/>
    
    <application
        android:label="hage"
        android:name="hoge"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="false">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.health.ACTION_SHOW_PERMISSIONS_RATIONALE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity-alias
            android:name="ViewPermissionUsageActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
            android:permission="android.permission.START_VIEW_PERMISSION_USAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW_PERMISSION_USAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HEALTH_PERMISSIONS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
</manifest>

Expected behavior
I want to prevent the dialog This app can't access Health Connect from appearing.
Actual behavior
I tried to catch a exception of requestAuthorization method by a log tool.
But I could not get nothing.
Flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.3, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64, locale ja-JP)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
